# check null value on numeric column in where clause of query - SQL 2008

Tags: sql, null

I have the following WHERE clause. If the selection from the combobox is null, it will select all values. If it is not null, it will select rows where TB.Widget is equal to the combobox selection. The combobox is filled by the TB table. It works if the column is alphanumeric. How would would I get it to work if the column is numeric?

```
WHERE (:DBLookupComboBox1 Is Null) or (BL.Widget = :DBLookupComboBox1)
```

Comment: The SQL check `IS NULL` works on any field that can have a `NULL` value, numeric fields included. Perhaps the values from your numeric columns aren't `NULL`?

Comment: Are you sure your combo box is sending a null value as opposed to an empty string?

Comment: It is checking for null on the combobox selection. It might be possible that this particular report writer (Fast Reports) is setting no selection to a value when it is numeric. I've already checked to see if it is zero. The error message is "invalid argument". I can get the query to work if I initialize the value to zero when the combobox loads. I was just trying to see if I could get the query to work with a numeric column.

Comment: When I initialize the combobox to zero, I then check for zero instead of null. That will work.